# How to clone ServerResponse in Spring Boot Webflux

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am using Spring Boot `2.0.1.RELEASE` and functional endpoint for my REST web app. I want to add a custom header to all outgoing response, for which I have a filter. The problem I am facing is, how to clone the `ServerResponse` that's created by underneath handlers. `ServerResponse.from` builds a new `ServerResponse`, but only with headers and statuses. How can I copy the body?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? It seems like a pretty strange limitation of the API...

Comment: I have done it via `WebFilter`. Please check the class https://github.com/nnanda2016/springboot2-controller-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/demo/fn/web/filter/CustomTracingHeaderFilter.java . This allows modification to request and response headers `exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().add("X-Server-Trace-Id", span.context().traceIdString());`

Answer (score 0):

Most of the methods in the ServerResponse provide you with a BodyBuilder and with the bodyBuilder you can add your body using a BodyInserters object and hopefully one of its methods.  See below: -

```
ServerResponse.BodyBuilder bodyBuilder = ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.OK);
bodyBuilder.body(BodyInserters.fromObject("test"));
```

Comment: My apologies if I didn't make it clear, but my whole intention is to add some more headers (to all my outgoing responses) and I wanted to do that at a common place such as a filter. I don't want to tamper the response body that each handler has already created; rather to insert few headers. So, I can't use `BodyInserters` as you suggested.

Comment: Can you add the code for you filter to your question to see what you have so far

Comment: Please check https://github.com/nnanda2016/springboot2-controller-demo and the file is `com.demo.fn.web.filter.RequestTxContextFilter`. With the current code, I am getting empty body in response

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
X-Trace-Id: 34cb3eb8-9e66-4a02-83f1-0071a5c64516
content-length: 0
someCommonHeader: commonValue